# Cannot create an object of a generic parameter's class

Tags: typescript, oop

i'm a java developer struggling with Typescript.
I have an abstract class called Shape and two concrete classes that inherit it: Square and Circle. I also would like to hide the constructor to those classes and create a factory method getNewShape that will, based on an argument, decide which concrete c'tor to use. In java i would simply write (in Shape):

```
public static <T extends Shape> T getNewShape(T reference){
    // my logic
    reference = T.class.getInstance();
    return reference;
}
```

in Typescript i would like to now use it like so:

```
let myShape = Square.getNewShape(myShape);
```

I read in other questions that i can use:

```
in the consumer:
let myShape = Square.getNewShape(myShape, Square);

in Shape:
public static <T extends Shape>(ref: T, type): T{
   //my logic
   reference = new type();
   return reference;
}
```

but i prefer if i'm already calling getNewShape from the concrete classes i wouldn't need to add the Type in the parameters and typescript would just infer it from the T.

Update: adding the complete code:

```
    class Shape {
    constructor(){

    }

    public static getNewShape<T extends Shape>(ref: T, type: new() => T): T{
        if(ref) {
            ref.clear();
        }
        ref = new type();
        return ref;
    }

    protected clear(){
        console.log('clearing');
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape{
    protected constructor(){
        super();
    }
}

class Square extends Shape{
    protected constructor(){
        super();
    }
}

class App {
    private _circle: Circle = null;
    constructor(){

    }

    public setup(){
        this._circle = Circle.getNewShape(this._circle, Circle);
    }
}
```

Comment: The type of a zero-argument constructor function that makes `T` instances is `new()=>T`.  You can annotate `type: new()=>T` and it should compile.  But why do you want that `ref` parameter in there?  It's not doing anything.

Comment: Your original intent is to hide the constuctor; in that case, from where does the user get the reference shape to pass to `Shape.getNewShape()`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im calling a method of ref if its defined.I have a method 'clear()' in Shape that i call where i wrote //my logic

Comment: the basic idea was to create a 'smart' ctor that clears the reference if the ref is defined. im adding the complete code above.

Comment: also seems like type: new() => T is a valid type only for public constructors and mine should be private/protected.
Argument of type 'typeof Circle' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Circle'.
  Cannot assign a 'protected' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.ts(2345)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way forward:

```
abstract class Shape {
  public static getNewShape<T extends Shape>(
    this: { prototype: T }, // ctors have a strongly typed prototype
    ref: T
  ): T {
    if (ref) {
      ref.clear();
    }
    // assert that this is a constructor
    ref = new ((this as any) as new () => T)();
    return ref;
  }

  protected clear() {
    console.log("clearing");
  }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  private constructor() {
    super();
  }
  radius: number = 0; // add property
}

class Square extends Shape {
  private constructor() {
    super();
  }
  side: number = 0; // add property
}

class App {
  private _circle: Circle = null!; // yeah, how do you get this?!
  constructor() {}

  public setup() {
    this._circle = Circle.getNewShape(this._circle); // okay
    Square.getNewShape(this._circle); // error!
  }
}
```

The relevant pieces of this are:

- The restrictions that happen when a constructor is marked as `protected` or `private` are pretty strong, and you can't have it both ways.  If the constructor of `Circle` is not public, you can't call it inside `Shape.getNewShape()` because even protected constructors are only accessible from *subclasses*, not superclasses.  Luckily there are [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) which let us override the compiler's complaints inside the implementation of `Shape.getNewShape()`.  This isn't type safe, of course.  So you have to be careful.
- Instead of referring to a constructor of `T` as `new()=>T`, which (as you noted) doesn't work for things with `private` or `protected` constructors, we can instead make use of the fact that class constructors in TypeScript have strongly-typed `prototype` properties, which are also of type `T`, regardless of whether or not the constructor is public.  So `new()=>T` is out, and `{prototype: T}` is in.  Note that this doesn't properly convey the fact that the constructors will have zero arguments... combined with the type assertion above, it means you need to make sure that `Square` and `Circle` don't explode at runtime if you `new` them with no arguments.
- Instead of passing in the constructor as a parameter to `SomeShape.getNewShape()`, note that you're calling a constructor's static method, meaning that the constructor should be the `this` context for that call.  So we can do `new this()`.  And we can use a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) to prevent users from calling the method on the wrong constructor (`Square.getNewShape(someCircle)` should be an error).

Those are the active ingredients.  Minor details I still want to mention:

- I added some properties to `Circle` and `Square` to distinguish them structurally from each other and from `Shape` and from an empty class.  This is [important to do](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) in TypeScript, even with example code, if you want to avoid weirdness.  The type system in TypeScript is *structural* and not *nominal*; that is, types are recognized by their *shapes* and not their *names*.  If type/interface/class `A` and `B` share the same property keys and values, then the compiler treats them as the same type/interface/class, despite having different names.
- I still am not sure how someone gets their first valid reference to an instance of `Square` or `Circle` if the constructor is not accessible.  It seems like a bootstrapping problem to me; `Square.getNewShape(square)` gives me a new `Square` given an existing `Square`, but where does the existing `Square` come from?  Maybe there are some static instances of `Circle` and `Square` sitting around?  Or maybe you have another way of doing this? ... Or, and this is just occurring to me, maybe you think that `null` is a valid instance of `Shape`.  You don't use the [`--strictNullChecks`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#--strictnullchecks) or `--strict` compiler options?  You really should.  And then you can annotate `ref` as `T | null` instead of `T`, and the intention that `null` should be accepted will be made explicit.

---

All that being said, I'd really recommend not hiding constructors if you're just going to expose a static method that calls them.  That's pretty complicated and I don't know what it buys you.  Instead, consider just exposing the constructors as `public` and doing whatever housekeeping you were doing in `getNewShape()` inside the abstract `Shape` constructor:

```
abstract class Shape {
  constructor(ref: Shape | null) {
    if (ref) {
      ref.clear();
    }
  }

  protected clear() {
    console.log("clearing");
  }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  constructor(ref: Circle | null) {
    super(ref);
  }
  radius: number = 0; // add property
}

class Square extends Shape {
  constructor(ref: Square | null) {
    super(ref);
  }
  side: number = 0; // add property
}

class App {
  private _circle: Circle | null = null;
  constructor() {}

  public setup() {
    this._circle = new Circle(this._circle); // okay
    new Square(this._circle); // error!
  }
}
```

That looks the same to me, and doesn't suffer from trying to force TypeScript to do something it doesn't want to do.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!